# Xorg crashes randomly when playing flash video

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xorg, flash

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 x64, nVidia graphics with the "current" driver. Same happened with the "current-updates" driver.

Every now and then, while watching flash playback (not every time) Ubuntu crashes to login screen.

dmesg:

```
Xorg[8478] general protection ip:7f5f27e466a9 sp:7fffdda31ff0 error:0 in nvidia_drv.so[7f5f27de5000+6e0000]
```

/var/syslog:

```
May 11 22:55:47 kernel: [22859.617181] Xorg[8478] general protection ip:7f5f27e466a9 sp:7fffdda31ff0 error:0 in nvidia_drv.so[7f5f27de5000+6e0000]
May 11 22:55:47 gnome-session[8647]: Gdk-WARNING: gnome-session: Fatal IO error 11 (Zasoby chwilowo niedostępne) on X server :1.#012
May 11 22:55:48 acpid: client 8478[0:0] has disconnected
May 11 22:55:48 acpid: client 8478[0:0] has disconnected
May 11 22:55:48 acpid: client connected from 12626[0:0]
May 11 22:55:48 acpid: 1 client rule loaded
May 11 22:55:49 acpid: client connected from 12626[0:0]
May 11 22:55:49 acpid: 1 client rule loaded
```

The "Zasoby chwilowo niedostępne" line means "resources temporarily unavailable".

I'm using Firefox 12.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/973096

Please log into Launchpad and mark the bug as affecting you too.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using? I have seen this happen in Chrome (it uses hardware acceleration) if it doesn't like the graphics card, but not in Firefox. If you run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

do you have packages that are held back? If so run

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I had issues before with an Intel card that would randomly crash back to the login screen, and it was because I hadn't updated my Linux headers.

Comment: Everything is up to date. I'm using Firefox.